# An HTML problem where I need to position some info. to the left but I can't it always positions it to the center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing this program for my school using HTML where you can find your classmates by simply just typing your class grade.

Here is my Code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Find your Class</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script defer src = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "credits.html">Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href = "ci.html">Contacts and info.</a></li>
    
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <header>
            <h1>FIND YOUR CLASS AT ST. THERESE SCHOOL</h1>
            <h2>Created by Axel Palomino</h2>
        </header>
        
           <div class = "search-box">
            <input class = "search-txt" type = "text" name = "" placeholder = "What class are you searching?">
            <a class = "search-btn" href = "#">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

ci.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Find your Class</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script defer src = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "credits.html">Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href = "ci.html">Contacts and info.</a></li>
    
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <header>

            <h1>Contacts and Info.</h1>
           
        </header>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

credits.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Find your Class</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script defer src = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "credits.html">Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href = "ci.html">Contacts and info.</a></li>
    
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <header>

            <h1>Credits</h1>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

about.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Find your Class</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script defer src = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

       <style>
           .info1{
               font-size: 25px;
               margin-left: -10em;
           }
       </style>    
        <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "credits.html">Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href = "ci.html">Contacts and info.</a></li>
    
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <header>

            <h1>About</h1>
            
        </header>
        
        <div class = "info1">
            <ul>
                <li>Hello </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
        
    </body>

</html>
```

style.css:

```
    body {
        background-color: rgb(53, 55, 160); /* background color: Blue*/
        color: white; /*color: Maroon*/
        font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica; /* */
    
    }
    
    header{
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    
    h1 {
        background-color: rgb(197, 13, 13);
    }
    
    .search-box{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 35%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background: rgb(197, 13, 13);
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .search-box:hover > .search-txt{
        width: 240px;
        padding: 0 6px;
    }
    
    .search-box:hover > .search-txt{
        background: white;
    }
    
    .search-btn{
        color: #e84118;
        float: right;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #2f3640;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .search-txt{
        border: none;
        background: none;
        outline: none;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        color: black;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 0px;
    }
    
    footer{
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 570px;
      
      
    }
    
    footer h3{
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .button1{
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .button1:hover{
      background-color: rgb(53, 55, 160);
    }
    
    * {
      
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    
    ul {
    
    }
    
    ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      line-height: 100px;
    }
    
    ul li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica;
      color: white;
      padding: 0 20px;
      
    }
    
    
    /* header {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px; 
      }
      
      h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 15px;
        color: #8c6b48;
        background-color: white;
      }
      
      h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
        padding: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      
      h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 2.7;
        letter-spacing: 0.8px;
      }
      
      th {
        border: 2px solid #8c6b48;
      }
      
      table {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 20px auto;
      }
      
      td {
        border: 2px solid #8c6b48;
        width: 300px;
      }
      
      footer {
        margin-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 5px;
        background-color: #242f44;
        z-index: 5;
      }
      
      footer h3 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      
      .container {
        max-width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 800px;
      }
      
      .left {
        width: 150px;
      }
```

My problem is that when I run the code and I see the result every time when I want to go to a different page (ex.About, Credits, Contacts, and info.) and I want to write some text in and it always positions it to the center and I want it to be left. An example of the problem is shown on the About page.

Answer (score 0):

In the about.html replace  **margin-left: -10em;** with **clear:both;**

```
<style>
  .info1{
    font-size: 25px;
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thx, but how can I move it a little more to the right and make it an unordered list.

Comment: below the **clear: both;** add **margin-left:20px;**. it is unordered list but the bullet has been disabled in the style.css